# Unable to kill process with batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I'm unable to kill process with batch script it say access denied, but with task manager it works and i'm not getting access denied.

I use

```
taskkill /F /IM TASKNAME.exe /T
```

to determinate process.

Process i want to kill is some mysql service and adobe updater.

what i need to do to make it works?

Comment: You need to run your script elevated (_run as administrator_).

Comment: If you know the names you want to stop, why use `TASKNAME.exe`, try posting the exact batch file or cmd.exe commands you've tried and let us know precisely what happens when run compared to what you expect to happen. BTW, a process and a service may not necessarily be the same thing! **Do not post those within a comment, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47020842/edit) your question body instead.**

Comment: Sometimes Task Manager running as a standard (non-elevated) user can kill processes that can't be killed from the non-elevated command line via taskkill.exe. The problem is that taskkill.exe requests to open the process with the right to query information, which may be denied and cause taskkill to fail even if you have the right to terminate the process. As suggested above, generally the open will succeed if you're running as an elevated administrator -- except not for protected system processes.

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as administrator should be able to kill all processes that can be killed with task manager.